# Can't get userId on frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I've a reset password feature and this page is only accessed via a token that is sent to the user that request. It's a simple form to update the DB with the new password.

The problem is that on the frontend I can't get the user ID, but on the backend is 100% functional (tested via Postman and it worked). What I'm missing on the frontend?

**PasswordReset.jsx**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react'
import './passwordreset.css'

class PasswordReset extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            newPassword: ''
        }
        this.newPassword = React.createRef()
        this.newPasswordConfirm = React.createRef()
    }

    render() {

        const handleClick = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()

            if(this.newPassword.current.value !== this.newPasswordConfirm.current.value) {
                this.newPasswordConfirm.current.setCustomValidity("As senhas não são iguais")
            } else {
                const password = {
                    password: this.newPasswordConfirm.current.value
                }
                try {
                    let newPassword = await axios.post("/password/reset/:token", password)
                    console.log(newPassword.response.data)
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err.response.data)
                }
            }
        }
        
        return (
            <div className="reset">
               <div className="resetWrapper">
                    <div className="resetLeft">
                        <h3 className="resetLogo">Farm 2 Fork</h3>
                        <span className="resetDescription">
                            Você está aqui porque recebeu um e-mail com um link para alterar a sua senha.
                            Preencha os campos ao lado com sua nova senha vamos atualizar!
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="resetRight">
                        <form className="resetBox" onSubmit={handleClick}>
                            <input placeholder="Nova senha" required type="password" className="resetInput" 
                                ref={this.newPassword}/>
                            <input placeholder="Confirme a nova senha" required type="password" 
                                className="resetInput" ref={this.newPasswordConfirm} 
                                minLength='6' autoComplete='off'
                                onChange={e => this.setState({ newPassword: e.target.value })}    
                            />
                            <button className="resetButton" type="submit">Atualizar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PasswordReset
```

**passwordReset.js (backend)**

```
router.post('/reset/:token', async (req, res) => {
    const newPassword = req.body.newPassword
    const newPasswordConfirm = req.body.newPasswordConfirm

    if(newPassword === '' || newPasswordConfirm === '') {
        res.status(400).send('Preencha com a sua nova senha')
    } else if (newPassword !== newPasswordConfirm) {
        res.status(400).send('As senhas devem ser iguais')
    } else {
        try {
            const token = await Token.findOne({token: req.params.token})
            
            if(newPassword === newPasswordConfirm) {
                const user = await User.findById(token.userId)

                const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
                const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.newPasswordConfirm, salt)

                const newPassword = await user.updateOne({$set: { password: hashedPassword}})
                res.status(200).json(newPassword)
            } else {
                
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
})
```

The error I get on node is this:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'userId')
> at C:\xampp\htdocs\F2F\backend\routes\passwordReset.js:83:56

Answer (score 1):

You must use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org//docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) or add a check for the token value, like this :

```
const user = await User.findById(token?.userId)
```

because when token value  is falsy can't use userId property

Comment: I add this in the frontend, right?

Comment: @LucasSaladini no,  the issue on the backend in line 83 on passwordReset file

Comment: Right right, I thought the error was on the frontend

Comment: Okay, not showing this error anymore, just a bcrypt error saying that salt and data are required